# Open Location Markers green, Closed Location Markers gray?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am fairly new to the Google Maps API and am using version 3 to build a mobile web app that contains restaurant locations.  I would like to list all of the nearby locations on the map, but have the color of the marker indicate the restaurant's open status (i.e. green marker=presently open, gray marker=presently closed).

I could really use some information on how to get started with this project.  Anyone have some insight on how best to accomplish this or have a link to any good examples?

Thank you!

Comment: How much code do you require? The how to do it is relatively simple but only if you know how to produce a map with markers in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
var markerIcon = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=U|00AAFF|000000";

if(isStoreOpen){
    markerIcon = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=O|00FF00|000000";
}else{
    markerIcon = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=C|808080|000000"
}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(markerIcon)
  });
```